# UITabBarController is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I just drag and dropped a UITabBarController into XCode 6 xib. 
It comes with two viewControllers by default. 
[image]

But when I am trying to run app I am getting this
[image]

The thing is I am couldn't able to see bar button items and neither viewcontrollers.
How to deal with that?

Comment: please mark the post as answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you are using a storyboard, not an xib?  If not, then you need to use a storyboard, then go into your info.plist file and add the following key-value:

"Main storyboard file base name" : your_storyboard_file_name_without_the_extension

Then make sure in your project settings > deployment info > main interface, you also point to that storyboard.

Comment: not really, one can just use xibs without any storyboard.

Comment: DaTa do you know how to deal with it in .Xib?

Comment: @DaTa yeah, why don't you not be a douche and explain how to deal with it in .Xib?

Comment: @kidsid49 btw, did you check that you have set a background color on your xib UIView?

Comment: ok then I recommend you do it the way I said or you can ask DaTa if you insist on doing it the pre iOS 7 way

Comment: sorry, I didn't have time yesterday to put proper answer together. I was just referring to "If not, then you need to use a storyboard" that you said. see my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. your xib file has to be set as the "Main nib file base name" in your target's info.plist file, like on the screenshot (in my case the xib file is called Main.xib):
   [image: screenshot1]
2. in your application's delegate header file, the window property has to be declared as IBOutlet (so it can be set through interface builder):

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
3. in the xib file, create an object that will represent your application's delegate object - be sure to set it's Class to your delegate's class name (in my case the class's name is "AppDelegate"):
   [image: screenshot2]
4. create a window object in your xib - this will be the main window or you app.
5. connect application's delegate window outlet with window object:
   [image: screenshot3]
6. connect the window's roootViewController outlet to your tab bar controller:
   [image]

so this is how you do it with a xib. although, I'm not saying it's simpler than using storyboards..

Comment: please mark the post as answer if this answers your question. thanks.